# how to find a shell script is re-executable

Tags: linux, shell-script

how to find a shell script is re-executable and would not overwrite the configuration/any such changes made.

Something like **bash -x script.sh** is used to to debug a script, to check whether each line of the script is getting successfully executed or not.

What i meant is suppose **script.sh** is having commands to:

1. Create soft-link for some file
2. Changing some values to some configuration file.

So, such a script if I execute again and again, would the changes take into effect or it would overwrite and change system's configuration, how do we ensure such things ?

Comment: "re-executable" meaning what, exactly? are you perhaps confusing `bash -x` with `test -x`?

Comment: `[ -x filename]` is probably what you are after

Comment: Are you referring to the ability to, if the script exits early with errors, start executing from where the last run left off?

Comment: What i meant is suppose script.sh is having commands to create softlink for some file and then changing some values to some configuration file. So, such a script if i execute again would the changes take into effect or just come out, how do we ensure such things ?

Comment: You need to take care of this when scripting and make use of testing. There is no way to ensure something like that in an easy way from outside. Please ask a specific question when you have a specific problem.

Comment: I would suggest a specific set of changes such that the question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as reexecutability, as long as the script doesn't remove itself or change its executable permission bit. As that's what executability is about. It's the `x` you see in the first column while running `ls -l`. If it's set, the file can be executed (by owner/group/user). If it's not, then it can't. You can always try to execute anything with an interpreter like

```
bash some_file
```

But for this the file doesn't have to be executable.

The executable bit is what allows you to call (execute) a script by:

```
./script.bash
```

(or whatever it's called).